# Suppose $a,b$ are vectors in $V$ and $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $a + U = b + W$. Show that $U = W$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose  $a,b$ are vectors in $V$ and $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $a + U = b + W$. Show that  $U = W$.

attempt: We know that $a + U = {\{a + u : u \in U}\}$. And  $b + W = {\{b + w : w \in W}\}$. Then let $a= b + w$ for some $w \in W$. Then $w = a - b \in W$. 
And $b = a + u $ for some $u \in U$, so $u = b -a \in U$.
Then we have $a + u = a + (b-a) = b = b+w = b + (a-b) = a $. So $a = b$ for any $u \in U , w \in W.$

Can someone pleaese help me?  Thank you

Comment: You don't have to have $a=b$. For instance, with $V=\Bbb R^2$, and $U=W=\{(x,0)\}$, then $a=(1,0)$ and $b=(3,0)$ still works. Specifically, you said $b=b+w$, which is not true in general.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach I think they are looking for: take a vector $w_0\in W$. Show, presumably by using the vectors $a,b,w$ and $u$, that $w_0\in U$ as well (the key observation here is that $a-b=w=-u$ is in both $U$ and $W$ simultaneously). In other words, show that $W\subseteq U$.

Then do it the other way around.

Comment: ok i will try thanks